# SQL Server : Select WHERE Field may not contain VALUE

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct

I know the title is vague but I'm not sure how to phrase it.

I have a simple table (see image below).

I need to write a SQL statement that will retrieve a single record representing each `[UNIT_ID]` and `[ISACTIVE]` where `[ISACTIVE]` is the MAX for that particular `[UNIT_ID]`.

[image]

Ideally, the result should look like this (notice that `UNIT_ID=2` does not have `ISACTIVE=1`):

[image]

Doing a simple `[ISACTIVE] > 0` IS **NOT** what I'm looking for because then `UNIT_ID=2` would never show up in the record.

Here's what I've tried (failed):

```
SELECT 
    [ID], [UNIT_ID], [REV], [ISACTIVE], [DATE_ENTERED] 
FROM 
    TestTable 
WHERE
    ([ISACTIVE] = (SELECT MAX([ISACTIVE]) 
                   FROM TestTable 
                   WHERE ([UNIT_ID] = [UNIT_ID])));

-- This code only reveals two records (its missing record #4)
```

Any help on the matter is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.[ID], t.[UNIT_ID], t.[REV], t.[ISACTIVE], t.[DATE_ENTERED] 
FROM TestTable AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TestTable
  WHERE [UNIT_ID] = t.[UNIT_ID] AND [ISACTIVE] > t.[ISACTIVE]
)
```

or with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.[ID], t.[UNIT_ID], t.[REV], t.[ISACTIVE], t.[DATE_ENTERED] 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UNIT_ID] ORDER BY [ISACTIVE] DESC) AS rn
  FROM TestTable
) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the subquery doesn't use an alias for the `TestTable`. Should be

```
SELECT 
   [ID], [UNIT_ID], [REV], [ISACTIVE], [DATE_ENTERED] 
FROM TestTable ta
WHERE (
    [ISACTIVE]=
        (SELECT MAX(t.[ISACTIVE]) FROM TestTable t WHERE (t.[UNIT_ID]=ta.[UNIT_ID])));
```

Comment: I tried your code (first fixed to: MAX(t.[ISACTIVE]) ) but it still only reveals records where IS_ACTIVE = 1

Comment: See the edited answer  with aliases for both table usages.

Answer (score 1):

Like @forpas says, I think that the best option is this:

```sql
SELECT t.[ID], t.[UNIT_ID], t.[REV], t.[ISACTIVE], t.[DATE_ENTERED] 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [UNIT_ID] ORDER BY [UNIT_ID, ISACTIVE] DESC) AS row_number
  FROM TestTable
) AS t
WHERE t.row_number = 1
```

The only difference is the `order by` clause, that have to have those columns `UNIT_ID, ISACTIVE`.

Hope this can help you.